# How to reload the tab in tab group in titanium alloy

Tags: tabs, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have three tabs in my tab group. One tab is for change language. If user changes the language I should need to change the selected language for all the tabs. my tab group code is as follows,

```
<Alloy>
  <TabGroup id="myTabGrp"> //Tabgroup Added
    <Tab id="one">
        <Window class="container">
            <Label>This is the Home View</Label>
        </Window>
    </Tab>

    <Tab id="two">
        <Window class="container" id="winTwo">
            <Label>This is the second View</Label>
        </Window>
    </Tab>

    <Tab id="three">
        <Window class="container">
            <Button onClick="saveLang">Proceed</Button>
        </Window>
     </Tab>
  </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

All the ui text is losing from database. So How can I reload the tab on clock of proceed button in tab3.

I tried the following code,

```
function saveLang() {
  $.myTabGrp.setActiveTab($.two);
}
$.winTwo.addEventListener('focus',function(e) { 
   // How can I reload the tab2 here....
alert('focus');
});
```

If I try the following code everything is working fine but, It is taking too long to load it will struct for 3 sec and then loading the required output. I need to avoid the long loading time.

```
var homeWindow = Alloy.createController('index').getView();
homeWindow.open({transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT});
```

Any suggestions that how can we reload the tab with less loading time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some part of your question answered [here ( how to redirect from one page to tab in another page in titanium? )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27221416/3419997).

When you switch to tab two or **winTwo** or when you open tabGroup, there would be some function which you call to update your window UI. Maybe you will have something like following in `index.js` :

```
$.myTabGrp.open();
updateWin1();
updateWin2();
updateWin3();

function updateWin1() {
  var value = "Win1"; //fetched from local db
  $.win1Label.text = value;
}

function updateWin2() {
  var value = "Win2"; //fetched from local db
  $.win2Label.text = value;
}

function updateWin3() {
  var value = "Win3"; //fetched from local db
  $.win3Label.text = value;
}
```

Now in your **winTwo**'s focus EventListener call the `updateWin2` method ( like following ):

```
$.winTwo.addEventListener('focus',function(e) { 
  //Reloaded
  updateWin2();
});
```

*Note :* You can have any complex amount of UI manipulation in the method `updateWin2()`, according to your requirement.

P.S : If you are using Alloy models and collection concept, you should try [Alloy Data Binding](https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Alloy_allOS_en/page/alloy_data_binding.html).