# how to redirect from one page to tab in another page in titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I have two pages in my application. The first page has a tab group with three tabs. Now on click of button in second page, I need to redirect my control to first tab 2 in my first page. How can I do that.

My code is as follows,

```
<Alloy>
  <TabGroup id="myTabGrp"> //Tabgroup Added
    <Tab id="one">
        <Window class="container">
            <Label>This is the Home View</Label>
        </Window>
    </Tab>

    <Tab id="two">
        <Window class="container" id="winTwo">
            <Label>This is the second View</Label>
        </Window>
    </Tab>

    <Tab id="three">
        <Window class="container">
            <Button onClick="saveLang">Proceed</Button>
        </Window>
     </Tab>
  </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

second page,

```
 <Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
                    <Button onClick="submitFun">submit</Button>
                </Window>
    </Alloy>


function submitFun()
{
var homeWindow = Alloy.createController('index').getView();
homeWindow.open({transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT});
}
```

I don't wat load the full index page because it will take long time to load. I need to load only one tab in the index page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would have the code in `index.js` from where you open your **second page**; maybe like :

```
Alloy.createController('second').getView().open();
```

Now in `second.js` you can just call `close` method of the window to close current window and return back to `index`.

```
function submitFun()
{
   $.second.close(); //id of second window = second
}
```

Also now add a [`focus`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-event-focus) event listener in `index.js` for the `tabgroup` and navigate to the desired `tab`.

```
$.myTabGrp.addEventListener('focus',function(e) { 
   $.myTabGrp.setActiveTab($.two);
});
```

Comment: Correct, Now I did the same way. But I need to reload the tab on focus. There are some check boxes are there I need to clear the all selected values in before showing the page. How can I do that

Comment: answered in your [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27228149/3419997).